# Any similar stuff like Google Gear for iOS?

Tags: ios, html, manifest, google-gears

Google Gears provided support for offline browsing. This technology is no supported by Google.

I'd like to know:

1. Why was this technology dropped? Does it have anything to do with the adoption of HTML 5?
2. Are there any equivalent technologies for iOS?

I'd like to use such a technology to add an "offline mode" to iPad applications.

Some limitation of HTML5 offline mode [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328037/about-solution-of-offline-mode-for-online-html5-video-system).

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something specific about iOS, but why not use HTML5 offline storage? I think it's pretty much your only choice anyway, since you can't install anything like Gears on iOS.

Answer (score 2):

Almost everything Google Gears has is included in HTML5 and implemented by Mobile Safari.

If you want offline support, implement it in the HTML5 standard way and it will work in Mobile Safari. During development, you can use Safari/Mac to test.

If you are familiar with Google Gears, you will find that the HTML5 implementation is similar. So for example, if you want to use offline mode, you can read the HTML5 API in [Dive Into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/)

Comment: most agree, HTML5 can replace gears. But for the offline mode, manifest tech can not work for video file, such as video.mp4. It works well for HTML/CSS/JS/Image.

Comment: For iOS device? I think the problem is not Mobile Safari doesn't support caching video file. The problem is Mobile Safari doesn't cache any file with the size above certain number. It just refuses to do so, no matter you put it in the manifest or not.

Comment: True ? any specs to confirm this ? Thanks very much!

Comment: Please read this article: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/06/28/mobile-browser-cache-limits/